# Photoshop CS2 in Ubuntu 16.04 - can't enter password

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, wine, password, photoshop

I have installed Photoshop CS2 on Ubuntu 16.04 using WINE.

The first time I installed, it asked for the password and I skipped it, thinking I would put it in later.  I do have a password.  But, on running the program, it loads, then says "The Adobe Photoshop user name, organization or serial number is missing or invalid. The application cannot continue and must now exit."

I have tried re-installing to see if I could again have the opportunity to enter that information but to no avail.  I keep getting that message and shut down.

How can I overcome this?